# how to swap images on canvas in android?

Tags: android, image, rows, swap

I have displayed images from resource in my application as rows and columns randomly.
From those rows and columns i would like to swap the two images when user click on beside of images only.The following code will display the images in rows and columns as randomly.

```
   private void rand(int imagesList[][])
{
     Random generator = new Random();
     int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < MAX_COLS; j++)
        {
          int randRowPos = generator.nextInt(MAX_ROWS);
          int randColPos = generator.nextInt(MAX_COLS); 
          temp = imagesList[i][j];
          imagesList[i][j] = imagesList[randRowPos][randColPos];
          imagesList[randRowPos][randColPos]= temp;
      }
}
```

by using the above code i have displayed images as rows and columns.

Here how can i swap the two beside images from rows and columns?

please any body help me.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have privilege to add comment, so I am posting this as answer.
What do you mean by beside images ?
Is it when user will click on one image , it should get swapped with the image next to it ?
Can you also share the code where you have binned these images to view or any adapterview  ?

EDIT :

I too had similar situation at the times when absolute layouts were alive.
What I had done is as follows:

**Class:**

```
    public class PlayScreen extends Activity implements OnTouchListener

    private Panel mainPanel; // Panel for out display
    boolean firstClick = false;
```

**OnCreate :**

```
main = new Panel(this);
// Display the panel (calls the ondraw and updates the display)
setContentView(main,new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(screenwidth,screenheight));
// Listen for touchevents on the panel
main.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

**Panel :**

```
class Panel extends View
    {
        /*
         * Init a Panel to draw on and a paint to paint with
         */
        Paint mBitmapPaint;
        public Panel(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
        drawImages(canvas);
        }
    }
```

**drawImages :**

```
private void drawImages(Canvas canvas) 
{

        for(int i = 0; i<MAX_ROWS; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<MAX_COLS; j++)
            {
        int xpos = j*bmp.getWidth()+j*2;
        int ypos = i*bmp.getHeight()+i*2;
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), items[i][j],opts);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp,xpos,ypos,mBitmapPaint);
        clickzonex.add(xpos);
        clickzoney.add(ypos);
        clickzonei.add(i);
        clickZonej.add(j);

            }
        }

}
```

**OnTouch:**

```
onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) :

if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
{
// imply logic 
x = (int) event.getX(); 
y = (int) event.getY(); 

    for(int i = 0; i < clickzonex.size();i++)
    {
    if((x>clickzonex[i]) && (x<(clickzonex[i]+ bmp.getwidth())) && (y>(clickzoney[i])) && (y<(clickzoney[i]+bmp.getHeight())))
    {
    // we have a click in a zone so we get the card-number in that zone
    if(firstClick == false)
    {
    itemAti=clickzonei[i];
    itemAtj = clickzonej[i];
    firstclick = false;
    }
    else
    {   
    FirstItemToSwap = items[clickzonei[i]][clickzonej[i]];
    SecondItemToSwap = items[itemAti][itemAtj];

  // Now do the swaping using any algo you like.

    main.postInvalidate(); 
    firstclick = true;
    }
    break;
    }
    }
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
```

I have just tried to show you the logic using my own example and mixing it with your code. The main point is that in ondraw method just call drawcanvas and on touch just swap the items[][] and call postinvalidate method of Panel class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708324/how-to-swap-the-bitmap-images-on-view-in-android

Comment: please go through above link i have given code implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something like this once. I just swapped the image references in the array and did a redraw(`invalidate()`) on the whole thing.

```
void swap(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    // swap items[x1][y1] and items[x2][y2]
    ........
    invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are actually asking here, so please try to clarify the question.

One approach could be to use a ViewAnimator as a parent for each of the drawable ImageViews.

```
<ViewAnimator 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/slideshow_animator"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

Then once you capture the event that should trigger the swap, you can use the ViewAnimator to swap the View (in your case ImageView) it uses. You can even easily add an animation effect
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html