# How to swap the bitmap images on View in android?

Tags: android, bitmap, swap, touch-event

I am working with small application for display bubbles images on android screen.I have displayed all bubbles images from resource directory.I have implemented code as follows in view class.

**onDraw method:**

```
    @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);


    drawImages(canvas);

}
```

I have implemented drawImages() method as follows:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();   
private void drawImages(Canvas canvas) 
{

        for(int i = 0; i<MAX_ROWS; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<MAX_COLS; j++)
            {
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), items[i][j],opts);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp,j*bmp.getWidth()+j*2,i*bmp.getHeight()+i*2,mBitmapPaint);
            }
        }

}
```

By using the above method i have drawn images from items[i][j].
I have implemented the initialize() override method as follows:

```
 @Override
protected void initialize() 
{

    for(int i=0;i<MAX_ROWS;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<MAX_COLS;j++)
        {
            items[i][j] = ImagesStore.ImageList.get(list_Indx);
            list_Indx++;
            if(list_Indx == ImagesStore.ImageList.size())
                list_Indx = 0;

    }
    opts.inSampleSize = 4;
    width  = getWidth();
    height = getHeight();

}
```

By using above code i have displayed all the bubble images on my emulator screen.

Here i would like to swap the bubbles which selects two bubbles by the user simultaneously.

I have implemented onTouchEvent method for check the bitmap image item position on screen as follows:

```
               int x = 0;
               int y = 0;
               int tx = 0, ty = 0;   
           @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{

     tx = (int)event.getX();
     ty = (int)event.getY();
    int position;

        x=tx;
        y=ty;

        row = (y) / bmp.getHeight();
        col = x / bmp.getWidth();

        position=row*MAX_COLS+(col+1);

        Log.v("row", "=====>"+row);

        Log.v("col", "=====>"+col);

        Log.v("position", "=====>"+position);

    count++;

    if(count%4==0)
    {

    Log.v("count", "=====>"+count);


    //I would like to implement swap code here



    }   
    return true;
}
```

From the above code How can i swap(inter change the images) bitmap images implementation at onTouchEvent()

Please any body help me..............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please define the functionality that you desire as..

"Here i would like to swap the bubbles which selects two bubbles by the user simultaneously."

is not a complete sentence.